# Trying different ways to do a conditional and the output is not what expected (PYTHON)

Tags: python, pandas

I´m trying to modify some cells of a column base on a double conditional. The code should write "none" in the column "FCH_REC" (this column is originally filled with different dates) if column "LL" is equal to "201" and column DEC is equal to "RC". Also I want to write "none" in the column "FCH_REC" if column LL is equal to "400" and column "DEC" is equal to "RCLA". Next what I tried.

First I transform to string that columns.

```
table["FCH_REC"] = table["FCH_REC"].astype(str)
table["LL"] = table["LL"].astype(str)
table["DEC"] = table["DEC"].astype(str)
```

Second I tried this:

```
table.loc[(tabla['LL'] == '201') & (tabla['DEC'] == "RC" ), "FCH_REC"]  = None
table.loc[(tabla['LL'] == '400') & (tabla['DEC'] == "RCLA" ), "FCH_REC"]  = None
```

Third I tried this:

```
table.columns = table.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
table.loc[(tabla['LL'] == '201') & (table['DEC'] == "RC" ), "FCH_REC"]  = "None"
table.loc[(renove['LL'] == '400') & (table['DEC'] == "RCLA" ), "FCH_REC"]  = "None"
```

Fourth I tried this (this one is having problems with the syntax):

```
table["FCH_REC"] = table[["FCH_REC","LL"]].apply(lambda row: 
row["FCH_REC"] = "None" if row["LL"] in ("RC", "RCLA") else row["FCH_REC"] )
```

Fifth I tried this:

```
for i in list(range(0,table.shape[0])):

if table.loc[i,"DEC"] in ("RC", "RCLA"):
    table.loc[i,"FCH_REC"] == "NONE"
```

I don´t know what`s going on.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: may be your data has whitespaces, before applying mask check the out put of your conditions

Comment: I checked that the columns are with the same datatype and it is fulfilled, I also removed the withspaces with table.columns = table.columns.str.replace(' ','') and still not working . Thanks for the help

Comment: I said that's one possible way, what you can do is, print `tabla['LL'] == '201'` check the output weather your code puts True to all the conditions are not.

Comment: I checked it and all the columns involved in the conditional returns Trues and Falses where it is due. If your asking to check where given the conditions the return is a date I dont know how to do that yet.